Which field from `show slave status` should I use as the binlog position for on-going CDC in MariaDB?
I am following this guide to migrate my MariaDB RDS to AuroraDB.
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/migrate-self-managed-mariadb-to-amazon-aurora-mysql/
However I am not sure what should I set as mysql_binary_log_file_location in step 6 Reduce downtime associated with logical exports.
Ref: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/show-replica-status/
Is Read_Master_Log_Pos correct after I run show slave status; on the replica?

It should be Exec_Master_Log_Pos according to the doc.
https://mariadb.com/kb/en/show-replica-status/
Exec_Master_Log_Pos
Position up to which the SQL thread has processed in the current master binary log file. Can be used to start a new replica from a current replica with the CHANGE MASTER TO ... MASTER_LOG_POS option.
